# Getting nsuri in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I have Tree.ecore as source Metamodel. I need to write something like this:

```
model Tree driver EMF {nsuri="http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Tree"};
```

How can I get exact `nsuri` of my registered `ecore` in `eclipse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `@namespace(uri="Tree", prefix="Tree")` in your Emfatic metamodel, then the nsuri you're looking for is `Tree` (nsuri stands for "namespace URI")

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have generated the model code for your Tree.ecore
Then you get the nsuri and all other elements (like all EAttributes, EReferences etc) via the generated static Package class.
In your case it is probably called `TreePackage`.

So you get the `nsuri` like this:

`TreePackage.eNS_URI` or `TreePackage.eINSTANCE.getNsURI()`

Update:

If you only have the *.ecore file and want to know the uri, open the file with a text editor and look in the `<ecore:EPackage` tag at the beginning of the file. There you see the attribut `nsURI`

Comment: I want to use this tool: https://github.com/epsilonlabs/haetae
I must declare metamodels in transformation code. As said in the link I must write something like as I write in the question. I want to know if I declare uri of source and target metamodel(Tree.emf and Graph.emf) same as this link: http://www.eclipse.org/epsilon/examples/index.php?example=org.eclipse.epsilon.examples.tree2graph how should I write nsuri of them in the transformation code?

Comment: I never heard of haetae, but have you tried declaring it with your `Tree` nsuri? Do you know how to get the uri? I updated my answer

Comment: I have Tree.emf file at the start of this file `@namespace(uri="Tree", prefix="Tree")` was writen. I register this Metamodel in EPackege by right click on it. then I have ETL file and in this file I want to declare Tree Metamodel with that format. I need nsuri of this, I don't know how I should write the nsuri?

Comment: I have uri but I don't have nsuri.